# Azure assign role when creating VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am writing a program in Java that creates a VM instance in Azure, uploads a script to a container, and downloads and executes the script in the VM. However, I am currently facing a difficulty in granting the machine access to the container. I added

```
.withSystemAssignedManagedServiceIdentity()
```

to the machine creation. This however was not enough and apparently I also have to add Roles (in my case Storage Reader) to the VM. When I do it manually in the portal, after the machine has been setup, I then see via SSH that I have the access. But is there a way to do it in the VM creation process in my Java program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, you can use [`withSystemAssignedIdentityBasedAccessTo(String resourceId, BuiltInRole role)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.resourcemanager.compute.models.virtualmachine.definitionstages.withsystemassignedidentitybasedaccessorcreate.withsystemassignedidentitybasedaccessto?view=azure-java-stable#com_azure_resourcemanager_compute_models_VirtualMachine_DefinitionStages_WithSystemAssignedIdentityBasedAccessOrCreate_withSystemAssignedIdentityBasedAccessTo_java_lang_String_com_azure_resourcemanager_authorization_models_BuiltInRole_) method.

Here is the [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/fae262cb28fecb789f9fd8a956ecf93fc76dfdac/sdk/resourcemanager/azure-resourcemanager-compute/src/test/java/com/azure/resourcemanager/compute/VirtualMachineManagedServiceIdentityOperationsTests.java#L180):

```
VirtualMachine virtualMachine = azureResourceManager.virtualMachines()
                    .define(linuxVMName)
                        .withRegion(region)
                        .withNewResourceGroup(rgName)
                        .withNewPrimaryNetwork("10.0.0.0/28")
                        .withPrimaryPrivateIPAddressDynamic()
                        .withNewPrimaryPublicIPAddress(pipName)
                        .withPopularLinuxImage(KnownLinuxVirtualMachineImage.UBUNTU_SERVER_16_04_LTS)
                        .withRootUsername(userName)
                        .withRootPassword(password)
                        .withSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.STANDARD_DS2_V2)
                        .withOSDiskCaching(CachingTypes.READ_WRITE)
                        .withSystemAssignedManagedServiceIdentity()
                        .withSystemAssignedIdentityBasedAccessTo("<storage-account-resource-id>", BuiltInRole.READER)
                        .create();
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved me a lot of time searching and trying out things that wouldn't have worked!

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if I must specify the resource group and storage account or is there a way to allow access to all resource groups/storage accounts from this particular VM?

Comment: @vedsil Sorry for my oversight, looks it is also possible in java, I missed the `withSystemAssignedIdentityBasedAccessTo` method, updated my answer.

Comment: This looks like it's exactly what I need, I'll give it a try today! Thank you! Is there possibly also a function that can get me the storage account ID from eg. the name?

Comment: @vedsil Yes, you can, just use `StorageAccount account = azureResourceManager.storageAccounts().getByResourceGroup("<group-name>","<account-name>");
        System.out.println(account.id());`

Comment: unfortunately I got `Status code 403, "AuthorizationFailed", "The client '...' with object id '...' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/write' over scope '/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/resgroup/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storageaccount2845/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/9a11b2e7-7235-4bf9-8d74-61646434deef' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}:` Should I do something else before I try to assign identity based access?

Comment: @vedsil Yes, your client need to be the Owner or User access admin in the storage account -> Access control, otherwise you will not have the permission to assign the role.